# Would like a different nav menu on one specific page... not working

Tags: php, javascript, navigation, hashtag

Okay, first off, I am not well-versed in JS or PHP.  I can usually change an existing script around to do what I'd like, but not write something from scratch.  Any URLs I mention in this for examples are made-up.

With that in mind, I am designing a page using a template that has CSS, PHP, and JS all of which I have really modified.  Each page has a header, a nav bar, and a footer that are called with an include statement.  I understand that part.  However, on *ONE* of the pages, I would like to have a different nav-bar, and it won't change.

What I have noticed:  The JS seems to change the clicked URLs from, say http://www.example.com/test.php to http://www.example.com/#test.php

What would be the purpose for that?  Also... if I manually TAKE OUT the hashtag in the URL on the page that I want the new nav-bar, the new nav-bar shows!  However, then if I switch pages, it'll make the end of the URL like ...test.php#newpage.php

So I either need to figure out how to modify this to NOT put the hashtag in the URL (but if there is a compelling reason for it, of course, it can stay), OR how to get that one page to show the alternate nav-bar.  The alternate nav-bar is a table of contents, so the html has hashtags in it to direct users to specific parts of the page... could those hashtags in the html be conflicting somehow and that is why it won't show up, or??? GAH!

Any help would be appreciated.

Okay, here is part of the javascript... it is the only section where it looks like it is referring to # in the URL:

```
    var $fadeWrapper = $("#fade-wrapper"),
    $allNav = $("#main-nav a"),
    $allListItems = $("#main-nav li"),
    url = '',
    liClass = '',
    hash = window.location.hash,
    $ajaxLoader = $("#ajax-loader");

$("body").attr("id", "");    

if (hash) {
    hash = hash.substring(1);
    liClass = hash.substring(0,hash.length-4);
    url = hash + " #inside-content";
    $fadeWrapper.load(url);
    $("." + liClass).addClass("active");
} else {
    $("#main-nav li:first").addClass("active");
}
```

**UPDATE:  I have decided to just remove the javascript altogether.  In doing some reading, I have come to the conclusion that the hashtag is there just so the script can tell which page is active, in order for the CSS to highlight one of the items in the navbar.  It also has something to do with the animated gif that would show when you navigate pages.  Neither one of those items are important enough for me to pull more of my hair out trying to figure out this stuff :D  Thank you for your suggestions, though! **

Comment: It would help if you posted relevant samples of your code.

Comment: Definitely going to need some sample code on this one

Comment: Update your post with a chunk of your code which you need the assistance on/think where the problem lays

Comment: Thing is, I don't know which part is adding the # to the URLs, or the purpose of even having it there in the first place, so should I just post the entire script?  I could just send files to someone via email if that would be better...

Answer (score 0):

The hash tags are added most likely because the links you are clicking have an href value of #.

Couldn't you just create a new header file (if that is where the navbar code is), modify the navbar how you want in that header file, and include the new file instead of the current header on the page where you want the different navbar?

Comment: The page in question will not call a different header file either, it seems.  I made a different one that does NOT call the javascript, but it still calls the one that is on the other pages.  I have even taken the includes out ALTOGETHER on that page, and just added the code for the header and navigation, and that still will not work as long as the # is in the URL.